# Mercurial - revert the uncommitted changes after did "hg update -C"

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to Mercurial. I did `hg status` and I saw the files that changed since the last commit have `M` in front.  I then tried `hg update -C`. Is there any way I can get back the version of the files with `M` before I did `hg update -C`? Or am I pretty much screwed? :( since `hg update -C` discards any changes since the last commit

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, it's right there in `hg help update`:

```
options:

-C --clean     discard uncommitted changes (no backup)
```

The proper workflow would have been to `commit` your outstanding changes (which would presumably create a new head) and `merge` your commit with the revisions you wanted to import.

If you don't like having to commit a half-baked set of changes, check out the [`shelve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension) extension, which is designed exactly for this: It temporarily puts aside all or some of your uncommitted changes, allowing you to run `hg` operations before you bring them back again. (`shelve` is not distributed with mercurial, but I think `tortoisehg` may include it).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's take a look:

```
PS C:\dev> hg init foo
PS C:\dev> cd .\foo
PS C:\dev\foo> echo ":)" > file.txt
PS C:\dev\foo> hg add
adding file.txt
PS C:\dev\foo> hg com -m ":D"
PS C:\dev\foo> echo "DDDD" >> .\file.txt
PS C:\dev\foo> hg sta
M file.txt
PS C:\dev\foo> hg up -C
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
PS C:\dev\foo> hg sta
PS C:\dev\foo> dir


    Directory: C:\dev\foo


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         5/14/2013   4:06 PM            .hg
-a---         5/14/2013   4:06 PM         10 file.txt


PS C:\dev\foo> type .\file.txt
:)
```

It's gone.  :(  Sorry for the bad news!

Answer (score 1):

Some IDE's, like Intellij will separate from version control keep track of "Local History" I would check for that in a case like this.

Answer (score -1):

Quite late answer for Jason, but may help the others.

We had the same problem and FOUND A SOLUTION [here..](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-February/037077.html).

In brief:

1. type `hg heads` - you will see head of your changes is stil somewhere in the repository
2. copy ID of your head and type `hg update <id_of_your_head>`

Comment: This only works if you committed the changes.  In OP's situation (and mine) the discarded changes weren't committed.